Girsanov's theorem for Gaussian measures as the Cameron-martin theorem with a random shift
Let $H \subset E$ be the Cameron-Martin space of a Gaussian measure $\mu$ on a separable Banach space $E$. The Cameron-Martin theorem states that for all $h \in E$ we have $h \in H$ if and only if $\mu(\cdot + h)$ is equivalent to $\mu$, and then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is
$$
\frac{d\mu(\cdot + h)}{d\mu}(x) = e^{- \frac12 \|h\|_H + \langle h, x \rangle^\sim} \,,
$$
where $\langle h, x \rangle^\sim$ is the Paler-Wiener integral, i.e. the unique continuous extension of the canonical embedding $E^\ast \hookrightarrow L^2(E, \mu; \mathbb{R})$ to the whole of $H$.
I have been told that there exists a version (special case) of Girsanov's theorem which is a generalization of the Cameron-Martin theorem to the case of random shifts $h$. I have also seen Girsanov's theorem being used in this fashion. Yet I am completely unable to find a reference for this fact. Usually reference is given to a classical version of Girsanov's theorem involving Brownian motion, martingales, Itô integrals and so on. In particular, involving time. As I understand there should exist a version of the Cameron-Martin theorem with random shifts which does not involve differentiating between time and space in any way, instead purely using the language of Gaussian Measures on a separable Banach space.
My question is whether this does really exist and if so I would be very happy to know a reference :).
I know reference requests are not exactly high quality questions, but I think creating some clarification on Girsanov vs Cameron-Martin and a link to a reference as a findable page on Google would tremendously help others in my situation in the future. Thanks!

Look at Nualart's The Malliavin calculus and related topics, Theorem 4.1.2

That is pretty amazing, thanks! It is more involved than I expected. This seems like a great reference!
